# How can I cut and glue brittle foam panels onto my van without breaking it?

Tags: wood, woodworking, plywood

I brought some very thin (1mm) wood panel strips to glue into my van (over the insulation to make it look nicer).  However the wood is very brittle and thin, I have to attach it to some curved surfaces and I'm worried it's going to split or break.

Does anyone know the best way to work with wood like this, for example, would it make sense to pre-soak it in some water to make it more flexible before attaching?

[image: wood]

Comment: Veneers should be attached to rigid substrates.

Comment: Modular homes built in a factory and moved to the home owners building site are designed to “flex” as it travels down the road. Even if you get the panels attached, I doubt they’ll last if you don’t allow for movement.